# Go query (db2) delivers not all characters (utf-8) from table

Tags: go, utf-8, db2

complicated to express my problem, I try:

I have a DB2-Table (internal codepage CP850)

```
create table codes (code character(2))
```

with a dataset of utf-8 characters

```
insert into codes values('ÖÖ')
```

under linux the db2-clients `select * from codes` delivers

```
code
ÖÖ
```

as expected.

**Now for the Go part, thats problematic.**

my model looks like

```
package codes
type Code struct {
  Code db.NullString `json:"code" sql:"code"`
}
type Codes []*Code
```

and my query looks like

```
package codes
func FindAll()(Codes, error) {
  result := make(Codes, 0)
  row, err := db.Query(nil, 'SELECT c.code FROM codes c');
  //errorhandling...
  for rows.Next() {
    c := &Code{}
    rows.Scan(&c.Code)
    log.PrintLn(c.Code)     //  <== 'Ö'
    result = append(result, c)
  }
  return result, nil
}
```

This log only prints one `Ö` instead of both. I know it is because the rune `Ö` is not one byte in memory. But I do not know where to look for and fix as this is my first attempt to Go.

(anything missing? i can provide)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot scan into your struct, you have to scan into a `sql.NullString` variable or a `string` and then assign to your struct:

```
for rows.Next() {
    var s sql.NullString
    rows.Scan(&s)
    c := Code{Code: s}

    log.PrintLn(c.Code)     //  <== 'Ö'
    result = append(result, c)
}
```

Also: The field tag `sql` has no effect (or do you use sqlx? If yes you have to use StructScan instead of Scan)

Comment: still the same result: my "normal" datasets contains two characters, except those with two bytes UTF-8 encoding